# How to pass JSTL variable value into javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl

I want to show a popup when user clicks EDIT link.I have written the code mentioned below.
Link:-

```
<a href=javascript:MyFunc('${someVariable}');>EDIT</a>
```

javascript:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyFunc(somevariable){
<c:set var="someVariable" **value="123"**/>    
var answer=confirm("do you want to edit")
if(answer)
window.location="<c:url value='/edit/${someVariable}'/>";
}
```

When I use some user defined value,it works but I am unable to pass the value of variable from the Link.

Comment: What's that "user defined value"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of MyFunc('${someVariable}') in the anchor tag, I would try:

```
MyFunc('<c:out value='${someVariable}'/>')
```

Also, you probably will want to factor out the ${someVariable} from the window.location:

```
window.location="<c:url value='/edit'/>" + "/" + someVariable
```